# jquery select2 append selected item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to select an item from multi select jquery select2 with ajax

**HTML**

```
<select name="schools" id="schools" multiple='multiple'>
  <option value="-1000">select all</option>
  <option value="35102907">org1</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("#schools").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "ajax_controller.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
        return {
            a: 'getSchoolList',
            c: 'model_milk_contract',
            p: [params.term],
            cs: csrf
        }
    },
    processResults: function (response) {
      return {
         results: $.map(response, function(obj) {
            return { id: obj.org_code, text: obj.org_name };
         })
      }
    }
  }
```

});

but when one item selected, jquery says in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

then i tried to find the problem and after some time i found in below line of jquery core, `ret[i]` must be a `node object`, but what it gets is `array of node objects` and if i pass `ret[i][0]` to this function, it works!

```
fragment.appendChild( ret[i] );
```

what's the problem?!

Comment: The code you have provided is related to pulling down the list of items not appending them.Can you please share the code which fails?

Comment: the code that fails exactly `fragment.appendChild( ret[i] );` in core of jquery, when i select an item from list.

Comment: Please also include your HTML.

Comment: in fact `ret[i]` in this line, when i select an item is `[li.select2-selection__choice]`, while must be an object, not array of objects

Comment: Also, please include an example of your AJAX response.

Comment: response ajax something like: `[{org_code: 123, org_name: 'abc'}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I found the problem: 
my jquery was too old and its version was 1.7.1 while select2 version 4 needs min jquery 1.8.
thanks...